# update is not firing in aframe component

Tags: javascript, aframe

I read from the aframe docs that whenever we update the position or any other value the update of the attached component would fire I am just trying to fire the update on every position change.

This is the component:-

```
        AFRAME.registerComponent('checking', {
          init: function(){
            console.log("initialized");
          },
          update: function(){
            console.log("valueUpdated: "+this.el.id);
          },
          tick: function(){

          }
        });
```

update is being fired once with the init when the doc is loaded but not when I am doing this from the console like `obj.setAttribute("position","4 6 7");`
acc to the documentation it should happen right or I am making some very basic mistake?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think You are confusing a component with an entity. The entity is a container, which behavior and appearance are defined via components.
So the update function is firing at the beginning + when you change the component, like via setAttribute('checking','newValue').

---

You can do Your check either by:

including a listener for the 'componentChanged' event:

```
  this.el.addEventListener('componentChanged',function(e){
       if(e.detail.name==='position'){
          console.log(e.detail.newData);
       }
    });
```

checking if the position changed on tick, but that seems highly inneficient:

```
   init(){
     this.pos = this.el.getAttribute('position');
   }
   tick: function(){
     if( this.el.getAttribute('position') != this.pos ){
         this.pos = this.el.getAttribute('position');
     }
   }
```