# Aframe.io component update/rebuild after onchange in another js file

Tags: aframe

Hello I am new in WebVR and I will be pleased If you can help me.

I want to update my AFRAME init() variable after onchange my input in test.js and callback aframe(rebuild Aframe component). I would like do somethink like [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)from React.

I have two file test.js and aframe.js

test.js

```
const el = document.getElementById("inputItem")
el.setAttribute("type", "date")
el.addEventListener('input', (e)=> { console.log(e.target.value) }
//other logic
```

aframe.js

```
AFRAME.registerComponent("test", {
init(){
this.input = document.getElementById("inputItem")
this.input.addEventListener('input', (e)=> { console.log("input changed", e.target.value) } );
console.log("my input value", this.input)
}
update(){
if( this.input.value != document.getElementById("inputItem").value )
      {this.input = "New input"
      console.log("input changed", this.input)
  }
}
// some code here to build aframe element and append it to html  

}
```

so my console.log function inside aframe work only one time. After onchange input my update function doesn't response. I know the problem is aframe component is calling only one time.

I tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44964913/update-is-not-firing-in-aframe-component) and read about [component](https://aframe.io/docs/1.4.0/introduction/writing-a-component.html#using-property-data-from-a-lifecycle-handler). I don't know how to recall/rebuild afraime component after changing my input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you've mixed two ways of doing this:

**1. Using `setAttribute()` to trigger the `update()` functions**.

The `update` function in the custom component is called:

- once after `init`
- after any change made with `setAttribute(<component_name>)`

Here's an example of triggering `update` with `setAttribute` from an "external" `js` file (same behaviour, as long as the script is loaded after the `<input>` element is attached) :

```js
const input = document.getElementById("logtext"); // grab the input 
input.addEventListener("input", e => {
  // on each 'input' event
  const text = e.target.value; // extract the text
  // set the [logger] "text" attribute, to trigger the update
  document.querySelector("[logger]").setAttribute("logger", "text", text); 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.4.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script>
  AFRAME.registerComponent("logger", {
    schema: {
      text: {
        default: ""
      }
    },
    // on any update
    update: function() {
      this.el.setAttribute("text", "value", this.data.text); // update the text component
    }
  })
</script>

<div style="position: fixed; z-index: 999">
  <label for="logtext">Text to be rendered:</label>
  <input type="text" id="logtext" name="logtext"><br><br>
</div>
<a-scene>
  <a-text position="-1 1.75 -3" value="" color="black" logger></a-text>
  <a-box position="0 1 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9"></a-box>
</a-scene>
```

**2. Using event listeners.**

You can add any logic you want to the event listener callbacks. It can modify you own component, it can modify other components.

Here's an example of modyfing another component with `setAttribute()` in reaction to an event coming from the `<input>` element:

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.4.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script>
  AFRAME.registerComponent("logger", {
    init: function() {
      // grab the input element
      const input = document.getElementById("logtext");
      // on "input", do whatever you need with the updates
      input.addEventListener("input", e => {
        const text = e.target.value; // extract the text from the event
        this.el.setAttribute("text", "value", text); // update the text component
      });
    }
  })
</script>

<div style="position: fixed; z-index: 999">
  <label for="logtext">Text to be rendered:</label>
  <input type="text" id="logtext" name="logtext"><br><br>
</div>
<a-scene>
  <a-text position="-1 1.75 -3" value="" color="black" logger></a-text>
  <a-box position="0 1 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9"></a-box>
</a-scene>
```

---

I think the first option is similar to react since:

- using the `schema` is similar to keeping a component "state" (as in `useState`)
- the `update` function reacts to the component changes (as is `useEffect`)

Comment: I have a question. Is it any way to skip the first call update after init?

Comment: it would be best if you could use the first `update` to your advantage, otherwise you can do a dirty hack like `if(!this.initialized) return; this.initialized = true;` inside the update function. Do you have an example where it's an issue?